# Styling components by extending their class

Tags: delphi, object, styling

From this question [Passing object in reference / one place to style objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437463/passing-object-in-reference-one-place-to-style-objects/5438472#5438472)

I was just thinking, what about if I created a descendant class for the item I am styling.

eg (excuse the poor code, not in ide, but you should get what I mean)

```
TStyledButton = class(TButton)
  public 
     constructor Create; //This overrides the main TButton
end;

constructor TStyledButton.Create;
begin
   inherited;
   self.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Then in my form I just have the Button1 as a TStyledButton instead.

This would remove all extra code in the form create to handle setting styles/calling function to set styles.

The only issue is, how would this go down in the design view, will I have to register this Object (component?) so it actually shows up as usual in design view.

Comment: Having your own suite of components and controls that descend from the standard VCL components brings many benefits, at the cost of a little extra plumbing. As for how to get these components into the designer, it's all well-documented as I recall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you learn about [Delphi packages](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_Packages) component writers, you can use the IDE expert to create a new component automatically add it to the component palete while creating a new design time package:

Start by creating it using the IDE expert in Component/New component:

[image: New component]

[image: New component]

When prompted, select Install to new package

[image: New package]

Provide the package (file) name and description

[image: Package name]

and voila!, you have your new component in your palette:

[image: Component installed]

Try this code:

```
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation
uses Graphics;

{ TMyButton }

constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Caption := 'Click me!';
end;
```

You'll get this:

[image: My Button!]

Comment: Ran into a major issue here :( When you drop a component on a form it runs thats components 'create' method which is not re-run at run time... that means any style changes AFTER the component has been dropped on the form which are tweaked in the extended objects create method will have no effect. It's almost like I need to re-run the create method at run time!

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it's Create is run, but then the settings in the IDE/Object Inspector are then inserted afterwards. Is there a method which runs AFTER the dfm values have been ran.

Comment: Solution: You need to override the Loaded method. So, create a new producture called whatever, then in both the Create and Loaded methods which you override, after Inherited call this new procedure. Works like a charm!

Comment: No, Wizzard, you shouldn't need to do anything in Loaded. It's OK that the stored properties are applied after the constructor runs. Either the stored properties are the same as the values you set in the constructor, so it makes no difference whether they're re-applied, or the user changed their values after placing the component on a form, and you shouldn't mess with it.

Comment: Rob, thanks. That would be true if I was redist my component but it's just for my own internal use. Thanks for the warning though.

Comment: If you don't want users to change the property values after putting the control on a form, then don't publish those properties in the first place. Descend from TCustomButton instead of TButton.

Comment: @Wizzard: Even if you're not writing components for re-distribution now, design it well, not just you'll learn better, but you'll also be prepared for tomorrow, when some of your employees will be using that _own internal use_ components and learning best practices from you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to register it so it shows up in design view.

It may be a good idea since you can always continue to change your component behavior. You needed to change the component style and in the future you may need another thing.

So, I would do that.

EDIT:

You can easily change all `TButtons` for your own type by creating an APP that will search the DFM and PAS looking for components like TButtons and change it to your own. Or you can use `GExperts` replace components function.